# Show HTML5 validation message

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using HTML5 Constraint Validation and I'd like to show validation message after each blur.

HTML

```
<input id="texInput" type="text" onblur="validation()" required>
```

JS

```
var el = document.getElementById('texInput');
if (!el.checkValidity()) {
    //Here show message
}
```

Is it possible to do something similar?

[image: valid-massage]

Comment: My requirement is same as your. So can you explain me how you can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I meant something like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity

Comment: If you want to post a suggestion use comments or point out in your question itself with EDIT:-

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.
Like this:

HTML:

```
<input id="texInput42" type="text" onblur="function(){validation('texInput42');}" required>
```

JS:

```
function validation(_id){
    var isValid= false;
    //check validity here:
    var el = document.getElementById(_id);
    if(el.innerHtml == '') isValid=false; 
    if(el.innerHtml.length > 0) isValid=true; 

    if (isValid) {
      //Here show message
      alert('debug: it's ok');
      //or change css to color el in green, e.g.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already checking validation with checkValidity. I meant the message like on the picture.

Comment: @LadislavMaxa oh I havent got it displayed. That's so easy. What do you want to know ? making such a message ?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually trigger HTML5 form validation like so:

```
$('input').blur(function(e) {
    e.target.checkValidity();
});
```

Obviously the above is with jQuery, but you can just as easily adapt for pure JS.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<!-- anywhere in your page, at the bottom e.g.->
<div id='myabsdiv' ><span class='icon'> </span> <span class="text">Please ...</span> </div>
```

JS:

```
  if (!el.checkValidity()) {
        //Here show message
        //show an absolute div...
        $("#myabsdiv").css('top', el.offset.y+el.height());
        $("#myabsdiv").css('left', el.offset.x - $("#myabsdiv").width()/2);
        $("#myabsdiv").show();
    }
```

CSS:

```
#myabsdiv{
    height:50px;
    width:180px;

    position:absolute;
    display:none;

    background-image:url('make a PNG');
}
```